# How do I get the contents of a users message from another channel?

Tags: discord, python-3.7, discord.py

I'm trying to get a users message from one channel and have it posted to another by the bot.

I've tried this but get a not callable error, where the ID posted is the ID of the users message.

```
await channel.send(message.content(608999881578774540))
```

I've also tried using message.id with the same issue.

I would like the bot to take the users message, just the contents of it and have it posted just like the message by the user. The message never gets deleted, it just gets edited so I wouldn't have to worry about getting the message ID as it stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Content in this case is not a method, therefore you should just take its value so that line would become this:

```
await channel.send(message.content)
```